# annual_interest_rate and result variables return undefined in expect assertions although I am assigning a value to them as per conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

In my expect assertions, variables **annual_interest_rate** and **result** return `undefined`. Can somebody help me sort out this issue? The code works fine on my local machine. It causes issue on Jenkins server. It returns output as follows:

```
 

      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
      - Expected 'Your AIR has been assumed at 5%' to equal undefined.
      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
      - Expected 'Your AIR has been assumed at 5%' to equal undefined.
      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
      - Expected 'Your AIR has been assumed at 5%' to equal undefined.
      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
      - Expected 'Your AIR has been assumed at 5%' to equal undefined.
      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
      - Expected 'Your AIR has been assumed at 5%' to equal undefined.
      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
      - Expected 'Your AIR has been assumed at 5%' to equal undefined.
      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
      - Expected 'Your AIR has been assumed at 5%' to equal undefined.
      - Expected '5' to equal undefined.
```

This is a code

```
    const COMM_BANK = '25',INST = '9',NBI = '75',PRI_FUND = '5';
    let annual_interest_rate, result;
    
    it('test the values', async () => {
            mbpPage.openTab(mbpPage.funding_requirements_tab);
            for(var i=0; i< await mbpPage.institutions_list.count()-1; i++){
                mbpPage.institutions_list.get(i).click();
                let institutionName = await mbpPage.institutions_list.get(i).getText();
    
                for(var j=0; j< await mbpPage.bank_name.count(); j++) {
                    mbpPage.bank_name.get(j).click();
                    if(institutionName == "Commercial Bank") { 
                        result = `Your AIR has been assumed at ${COMM_BANK}%`; 
                        annual_interest_rate = COMM_BANK; 
                    }
                    else if(institutionName == "Micro-finance Bank") { 
                        result = `Your AIR has been assumed at ${INST}%`; 
                        annual_interest_rate = INST; 
                    }
                    else if(institutionName == "Non-banking Institutions") { 
                        result = `Your AIR has been assumed at ${NBI}%`; 
                        annual_interest_rate = NBI; 
                    }
                    else if(institutionName == "Intervention Funds Private") { 
                        result = `Your AIR has been assumed at ${PRI_FUND}%`; 
                        annual_interest_rate = PRI_FUND; 
                    }
                    expect(mbpPage.getValue(mbpPage.loan_calc_air)).toEqual(annual_interest_rate);
                    expect(mbpPage.matchText(mbpPage.air_note)).toEqual(result);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What value does `let institutionName = await mbpPage.institutions_list.get(i).getText();` have?

Comment: institution_list is a dropdown and has these values: **Commercial Bank**, **Micro-finance Bank**, **Non-banking Institutions** and **Intervention Funds Private**. So institutionName will loop through each.

Comment: yes, this is what you think it is. But have you tried to `console.log` its actual values? Your problem is clearly because `institutionName` doesnt match any on your `if/else` conditions

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov it works very well on my local machine, but it gives an unexpected result on jenkins server though. I have tried printing its values using ```console.log``` that's not a problem as far as I figured out. The result posted above is from jenkins.

Comment: funnily enough, the same test passed on local.

Comment: I'm telling you, your `institutionName` is NOT what YOU think it is. It might be for tons of reasons, for example the resolution of your jenkins setup is different and thus the element is not visible. In this case `.getText()` would return an empty string. So the starting point is obviously to check what value is returned first, and then think how to resolve it. So again, place `console.log(institutionName)` and update the question with that information

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I'll see to it and get back to you. Thanks.